# Rails + Devise - Sending email to email + username in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, devise

I'm currently working on my first Ruby on Rails app and I found a bug which I don't know if I cause it or if it was already here.

I have Devise installed and configured, a user seeded using Rake and my views a properly set. The problem, when I try to send a confirmation email, it tries to send an email to: `['admin@domain.com', 'admin']`.

As you may think, it crashes because the SMTP server refuse to send an email with a invalid address.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Here's the log generated on error:

```
Devise::Mailer#confirmation_instructions: processed outbound mail in 26.0ms

Sent mail to ["admin@domain.com", "admin"] (5054.3ms)
Date: Mon, 23 Nov 2015 14:45:01 -0500
From: support@domain.com
Reply-To: support@domain.com
To: ["admin@domain.com", "admin"]
Message-ID: <56536cbda3561_55446c9740595c9@freud.mail>
Subject: Confirmation instructions
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<p>Welcome [&quot;admin@domain.com&quot;, &quot;admin&quot;]!</p>

<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>

<p><a href="http://localhost:3000/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=z4pUucoe1GKD-mCbTkji">Confirm my account</a></p>

   (3.0ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5092ms (ActiveRecord: 6.0ms)

Net::SMTPSyntaxError - 501 5.1.3 Invalid address
```

Here's the `User` class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  acts_as_paranoid

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable

  before_save { self.email = email.downcase, self.username = username.downcase }

  after_update :send_password_change_email, if: :needs_password_change_email?

  validates :username, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :role, presence: true, inclusion: { in: %w(user manager admin) }

  def is_admin?
    self.role == 'admin'
  end

  private
    def send_devise_notification(notification, *args)
      ## It crashes here!!!
      devise_mailer.send(notification, self, *args).deliver_now
    end

    def needs_password_change_email?
      encrypted_password_changed? && persisted?
    end

    def send_password_change_email
      UserMailer.password_changed(id).deliver_now
    end
end
```

And the seed:

```
admin = User.new(username: 'admin', password: 'admin1234', email: 'admin@freudtech.com', role: :admin)
admin.save!
```

Comment: Could you post the relevant part of the devise model and how you seed the user?

Comment: Are you trying to write a check to rescue an invalid mail? Or are you asking for a way to emails work on the development environment with any email given?

Comment: @SunnyK In fact, I just want the email to send but this little bug that take the username as an email address is annoying.

Comment: @MarcoSandrini Done!

Comment: You have: `devise_mailer.send(notification, self, *args).deliver_now`. Can you show your mailer class?

Comment: @SunnyK It is using the Devise default mailer, the override of the method is only for future purpose when `.deliver_later` will be enabled using Sidekiq or Resque.

Comment: the problem is in your before_save filter, you are actually setting the email field to [email.lowercase, username.lowercase], change the comma to a semicolon

Comment: @MarcoSandrini Post that as an answer, it was good! I didn't know that Ruby make a difference between `,` and `;` in a hash!

Comment: That's not a hash, it is a single-line block (delimited by the braces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `before_save` filter, which effectively sets the `email` field to an array. Possible alternative syntaxes are

```
self.email = email.downcase; self.username = username.downcase
```

or using Ruby's multiple assignment

```
self.email, self.username = email.downcase, username.downcase
```

On a separate note, if you want to send devise emails in background using devise and resque, I suggest you take a look at the [devise-async](https://github.com/mhfs/devise-async) gem, as it is advised by the [devise guys themselves](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Send-devise-emails-in-background-%28Resque%2C-Sidekiq-and-Delayed%3A%3AJob%29)

Comment: What is best for background jobs? `Sidekiq`, `Resque` or `ActiveJob`? I like Sidekiq because I already saw it in GitLab but I don't know if it is the best one.

Comment: There is no silver bullet, it very much depends on what your app does and where you plan to deploy it. I like Sidekiq, but you have to be extra careful to be thread-safe both in your apps and in the gems you use.

Comment: Well, I need to be able to queue task as well a doing recurrent tasks.

Comment: My advice then is go with sidekiq, and sidekiq-scheduler (for the recurring tasks), but be prepared to switch to another background tasks solution in case you have troubles with thread-safety. Which is essentially my strategy for the project I am currently working on.